# Php script closing text field when echoing database contents

Tags: php, mysql, echo, textfield

I am trying to load the contents of a database row into a textfield, the problem I am having is that the content I want to load into the textfield box has text field code inside it, so instead of the row being loaded into the textfield what is happening is its loading all of the row content into the textfield until it gets to the closing tax  , it is then closing the textfield and echoing the remaining code on the page itself.

[image]

The code I am using looks like this >>

```
  <?php
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u5b0y_chronoforms WHERE id='4'");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {$content = $row['content'];
   }

   echo '<textarea style="width:800px; height:500px;" name="" cols=""                 rows="">'.$content.'</textarea>';

   ?>
```

The content that is getting loaded looks like this, it gets to the textfield closing tag and then closes the textfield instead of loading it all into the textfield.

[image]

Comment: Please learn how HTML works. Your PHP script is only generating HTML and it made an error generating the HMTL. If you need to encode HTML to display inside HTML in PHP automatically, use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output HTML inside HTML without actually making the browser rendering (display) it as HTML, you need to encode it so it still looks like HTML (in the browser) but is just the HTML as text:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars($content);
```

You can then just echo it into the textarea:

```
echo '<textarea style="width:800px; height:500px;" name="" cols="" rows="">', 
      $text, '</textarea>';
```

or similar. See http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Additionally watch your parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo the content between the tags like

```
<?php
  $fetch_content = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM table_name"));
?>
<textarea><?php echo $fetch_content['column_name']; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: I have tried using this, but still get the same problem  >>
 <textarea style="width:800px; height:500px;" name="" cols="" rows="">'<?php echo $content; ?> </textarea>

Comment: The question is edited I guess, you are fetching the data from the database so probably the markup over there is wrong